# "Как угодно"

Tags: пунктуация

Отделяется ли запятой выражение "как угодно" в предложениях типа "его смысл можно трактовать(,) как угодно"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, запятая не нужна. Это оборот, составляющий единое смысловое целое со сказуемым. Такие обороты не обособляются.

Answer (score 1):

Трактовать как угодно - ср.: трактовать по-разному. Запятая не нужна.

Comment: Запятая-то не нужна, а насколько вообще применим метод синонимичной замены в подобных случаях?
Можете поступать(,) как (вам) угодно -  можете поступать по-разному.
Здесь отсутствие запятой мне совсем не очевидно.